# selenium - xpath stored from a string

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a global variable string and I need to click on a web element using that global variable as part of the xpath.

So for example global variable is a = bob154;

I know the following below works

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='bob154]")).click();
```

but I want to do something like this below and just use the global variable instead but that does not work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()=a]")).click();
```

If you have any suggestions on what I can do will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put the 'a' inside double quotation "as this example", the code will consider it as string, and not a variable.

To the code recognize your 'a' as a variable, you need to separe it:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='" + a + "']")).click();
```

> **"//a[text()='"** will be the first string
>
> **a** is your variable
>
> **"']"** is the last string
>
> **"//a[text()='" + a + "']"** is your dynamic xpath

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just simply use addition of strings:

```
"//a[text()="+ a +"]"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect because your global variable is in double quote. Try code below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='"+a+"']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='"+a+"']")).click();
```